# find and sed string in docker got error ` Device or resource busy`

Tags: sed, find, docker, xargs

This problem only happen in docker container.

Only `find` is fine:

```
find ${BASIN_SPIDER_CONFIG_PATH} -type f -name "*.json"
```

`find` with sed

```
find ${BASIN_SPIDER_CONFIG_PATH} -type f -name "*.json"|xargs sed -i "s/10.142.55.199/host02/g"
```

gives an error:

```
/xxx/config/sed8Ey5tD: Device or resource busy
```

I don't understand what is `sed8Ey5tD` , `ls` can't see it. I think it is by docker, but can't figure it out.

How to make `sed` success?

---

OK, I found that file is being volumed by docker , there is  `volumes: /xxx/config.json : /xxx/config/config.json`  in `docker-compose.yml`. After `docker-compose down`, the file can be edit . But how do I edit the file without `docker-compose down` ?

Comment: It's temporary file created by `sed`. When you do in-place modification, `sed` will create a temporary file to work on to prevent corrupting your original. If anything went right, then it replace the original with temporary one. But what is your question? You want to know which cause that error or what is `sed8Ey5tD` file?

Comment: @cuonglm I want to know how to make sed success.

Comment: are you sure that you have write permissions inside the container?

Comment: @user1700494 root user

Comment: you may try to force `sed` to make no backup file `xargs sed -i'' "s/10.142.55.199/host02/g"` (add single quotes right after `-i` key)

Comment: Does the command work without `-i` option? Can you edit the file?

Comment: I have update the question,   I found that file is being volumed by docker which result this error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, as you found, the file is mounted by docker, which means you are not allowed to change its inode from within docker container. But, what if you only change the content of file without touching its inode, does it work? Sure, it does. So all you need to do is to find a way to change the content of original file only, rather than create a new file and then replace the original one.

Command `sed` with option `-i` does create new file, and then replace the old file with the new one, which definitely will change the file inode. That is why it gives you the error.

So, which ways can change the content of file? Many many ways.

1. shell redirect, e.g., `echo abc > file`
2. command `cp`, e.g., `cp new old`
3. vim
4. ed

Give you several examples for how to fix your issue:

The `cp` way:

```
find ${BASIN_SPIDER_CONFIG_PATH} -type f -name "*.json" | xargs -L1 bash -c 'sed "s/10.142.55.199/host02/g" $1 > /tmp/.intermediate-file-2431; cp /tmp/.intermediate-file-2431 $1;' --
```

The `vim` way

```
cat > /tmp/vim-temp-script <<EOF
:set nobackup backupcopy=yes
:let i = 0
:while 1
:  let i += 1
:  %s/10.142.55.199/host02/g
:  if i >= argc()
:    break
:  endif
:  wn
:endwhile
:wq
EOF
find ${BASIN_SPIDER_CONFIG_PATH} -type f -name "*.json" | xargs vim -s /tmp/vim-temp-script
```

The `ed` way

```
find ${BASIN_SPIDER_CONFIG_PATH} -type f -name "*.json"|xargs -L1 bash -c 'ed $1 <<EOF
,s/10.142.55.199/host02/g
wq
EOF' --
```

Comment: could you please share additional documentation that backs your statements about inode in a container. I want to study further.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` has a `-c` option to use with `-i` so that it does copy instead of move, which makes this work.

This works:

```
RUN sed -ci "s/localhost/foobar/g" /etc/hosts
```

Note carefully, however, that `sed -ic` won't work, as it would make a backup file ending in `.c`, rather than doing what `sed -i -c` or `sed -ci` does.

Cleaned up a docker script today from this learning :)

Comment: What version of sed are you using? My version, GNU sed 4.7, has no 'c' option.

Comment: [sed](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sed.1.html) 4.8 included in Ubuntu 22.04, does not have the `-c` option.

Comment: Adding `-c` to `sed` is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 2):

Imho, the easiest way to do is by using the following in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts2 && sed -i 's/::1  localhost/::1/g' /etc/hosts2
CMD cat /etc/hosts2 >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: avoid duplicating `CMD cat  /etc/hosts2 > /etc/hosts`